# Exercise 28 of Chapter 1 in Stein-Shakarchi's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am doing an exercise [similar to] Exercise 28 in Chapter 1 of Stein-Shakarchi's [Real Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8008.html) (page 44):

> For any $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}^d$, $0 < \alpha <1$, we can find an open set $O \supseteq E$ such that $m_\ast(E) > \alpha m_\ast (O)$ where $\ast$ means the exterior measure.

I am not sure how to say this but am I correct when I say that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $O$ open such that $m_\ast(O) - m_\ast(E) < \epsilon$. But from here how to get the result they claim?

Also saying that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $O$ open such that $m_\ast(O) - m_\ast(E) < \epsilon$ is not the same as saying there is $O$ open such that $m_\ast(O - E) \leq \epsilon$ yes?

---

[Added by @Jack, 6/29/19] The problem in OP is not the original exercise in the book:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just choose $ 0 <\epsilon < m_*(E)(1-\alpha)/\alpha $, then you have $ \alpha (m_*(E)+\epsilon)<m_*(E) $, Now there exists open $ O \supseteq E $ such that $ m_*(O) < m_*(E) + \epsilon $, hence 
$$ \alpha m_*(O) < \alpha(m_*(E)+\epsilon) \leq m_*(E) $$

Comment: @Kyle As a remark, your last statement is correct, that is they are not the same, but it is also true that given $\epsilon $ you can find $ O\supseteq E$ such that $ m_*(O\setminus E) \leq \epsilon $.

Comment: Dear smiley06, $E$ here is just any subset of $\Bbb{R}$. Why can we always find $O \supseteq E$ open such that $m(O  - E)\leq \epsilon$? I believe this is true only when $E$ is measurable though?

Comment: @BenjaLim Yes you are right, in general $E$ has to be measurable, but if $m$ is regular, then for any $E$ we have a measurable subset $B\supseteq E$ such that $ m_*(E) = m_*(B) $, so the result follows. In this exercise $m$ is probably the lebesgue measure.

Comment: Hmmm I think in Stein and Shakarchi they use $m_\ast$ to mean the exterior measure which one can associate to ***any*** set, not just a Lebesgue measurable one.